# How to make sure a task is run at Windows startup?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have trouble running a PowerShell script and/or and .exe file on boot with Windows (both win10 and win11). I have tried multiple methods:

1. Put the script inside `shell:startup`
2. Create a task with Task Scheduler
3. Run the task as a Windows service

Sometimes it runs, sometimes it does not. I have a feeling that Windows runs the task whenever it feel like to do that. On Linux, if I put the task inside cron, it is guaranteed to run.

Here is an example of a Windows service which is not run most of the time (but sometimes it does run):
[image]
I have tried both `Automatic` and `Automatic (Delayed start)`, yet the results are the same.

If you are curious, I want to run `aria2c.exe` in RPC mode, so I create a task in Task Scheduler for it. I also want to run a `.ps1` script so I put it inside the startup folder. And the VirtioFS service was created by default by the installer to start a virtual drive at boot. Yet everything behaves out of my control. What could be the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Copying a .ps1 script into `shell:startup` will only try to open the file with notepad when you log in by default (like a .bashrc entry). Take a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189430/7411885) for how to get a powershell script to launch from that folder.

Note: The system startup folder is actually `shell:common startup`

The task scheduler triggers "When the computer starts" and "When I log on" work fine, but need to be defined properly. This command run as admin works well to create one automatically:

```
schtasks /create /tn "FileMonitor" /sc onstart /delay 0000:30 /rl highest /ru system /tr "powershell.exe -file C:\Path\To\Script.ps1"
```

Be aware that windows won't run arbitrary powershell script files by default. You can view that with `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`, and change it with `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine` for scripts running as System.

---

As far as that particular service not starting, check the event logs. It probably does start but crashes - make sure your virtiofs drivers are up to date

Comment: For a Windows Service, you can set startup type as delayed start, https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/startup-types-explained/ or make it wait for dependencies, https://www.digitalcitizen.life/windows-services-identifying-dependencies-changing-startup-type/ , if other Windows components need to start first.